# creating an object from a class in python in shortest form

Tags: python, class, dictionary, object, self

I have this class in python, for crating an empty Box type dictionary, Box is a library for extending ways of working with dictionaries:

```
from box import Box

class Ipsm():
    def __init__(self):
        self.ipsm = Box(default_box=True)

def ipsmAddElement(self, box_dots):

    def validIpsmAddElementLine(self, box_dots):
        if box_dots:
            return True

    if validIpsmAddElementLine(self, box_dots):
        eval(f"self.ipsm.{box_dots}")

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    box = Ipsm()    
    print(box.ipsm) #{}
    box.ipsmAddElement("IP.nested_elem")
    print(box.ipsm) #{'IP': {'nested_elem': {}}}
    box.ipsm.IP.nested_elem = "127.0.0.1"
    print(box.ipsm.IP.nested_elem) #127.0.0.1
```

Is it possible to re-write the class (adding another method...) so that I don't have to use "box.ipsm" to get to this dictionary to add my keys. For instance, just doing box.IP.nested_elem = "127.0.0.1", should get me to that result.

Comment: What is `Mybox` supposed to do for you, that using `Box` directly wouldn't?  Perhaps making your class a subclass of `Box` would be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, I added the the other function, hopefully now it is clear.

Comment: What you can do is inherit from the structure ```dict``` in this way: ```class className(dict): # Code...```. Add items inside the class using ```self['key'] = 'value'```.

Answer (score 1):

Classes do not work this way. Referring to an object will always get you that object, and you use `object.attribute` or `object.method` to access things within it.

As commenter jasonharper suggested, you should probably subclass Box, by using this syntax:

```
class MyBox(Box):
    # ...
```

Your new subclass will inherit everything in Box and will work just like it, but with anything you add included.

Edit:

If you're not adding any other methods or attributes to Box, no need to create a new class, just instantiate Box and it will work exactly as you want it to.

Comment: I am adding my own method as in my code above, so in this example how is the object initialized, how will the init method change inside class MyBox(Box): ?